Spring Security 6.3.3 WebFlux CORS
Setup

Spring Boot 3.3
Spring Security 6.3.3
Angular 18

Both server and client run on different hosts.
Spring Boot application runs on http://api.example.com.
Angular application runs on http://client.example.com.
Problem
Using the configuration bellow when i make a request to http://api.example.com/users/info with a valid JWT token the request passes through CORS WebFilter and AUTHENTICATION WebFilter and i get a user info json object both in postman and browser(chrome i don't this that this is a problem but just in case).
When i try with an invalid JWT token, let's say an expired one, then i get Unauthorized (401) status code witch is expected CORS error on browser console which is weird(to my understanding) because the valid request passes and no erro body on browser while i get a "correct" error body in postman.
The Spring Boot logs does not refer any header missing regarding CORS. I have just to lines of log for this request:

HTTP GET "/users/info"
Completed 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Spring Boot log information
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    io.r2dbc.spi: DEBUG

I am not an experienced Spring Boot developer so don't be hard on me on the implementation. Although corrections as appreciated.
Hope i provided all the information needed around this problem. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.
SecurityConfiguration.java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ResourceServiceSecurityProperties.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        "/users/login"
    };

    private final ResourceServiceSecurityProperties resourceServiceSecurityProperties;

    private final JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        http
                // Disabled basic authentication
                .httpBasic(ServerHttpSecurity.HttpBasicSpec::disable)

                // Disabled CSRF
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)

                // Rest services don't have a login form
                .formLogin(ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec::disable)

                .logout(ServerHttpSecurity.LogoutSpec::disable)

                // Disable Spring Security CORS we will use a CORS web filter.
                .cors(ServerHttpSecurity.CorsSpec::disable)

                .authorizeExchange(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                                    .permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, AUTH_WHITELIST)
                                    .permitAll()
                                .anyExchange()
                                    .authenticated()
                )

                .addFilterAt(jwtAuthFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .addFilterAt(corsFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.CORS)

                // Do not allow sessions
               .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())

                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServerCustomizer -> oauth2ResourceServerCustomizer
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveJwtDecoder reactiveJwtDecoder() {
        return ReactiveJwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(resourceServiceSecurityProperties.getIssuerUri());
    }

CorsFilter.java
@Component
public class CorsFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Mono<Void> filter(@NonNull ServerWebExchange exchange, @NonNull WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();

        if (request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)) {
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }

        request.mutate()
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", http://client.example.com")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE")
                .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, authorization")
                .build();

        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
    }
}

Also tried without mutating the request and the exchange.
JwtAuthFilter.java
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthFilter implements WebFilter {

    private final JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            "/users/login"
    };

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Mono<Void> filter(@NonNull ServerWebExchange exchange, @NonNull WebFilterChain chain) {
        if (Arrays.asList(AUTH_WHITELIST).contains(exchange.getRequest().getPath().value())) {
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }

        if (exchange.getRequest().getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)) {
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }

        return Mono.justOrEmpty(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("Authorization"))
                .filter(authHeader -> authHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
                .switchIfEmpty(
                    Mono.error(
                            new InvalidBearerTokenException("The token provided is expired, malformed, revoked, or invalid for other reasons.")
                    )
                )
                .map(authHeader -> authHeader.substring(7))
                .map(jwtUtil::isExpired)
                .flatMap(isExpired -> {
                    if (isExpired) {
                        return Mono.error(new InvalidBearerTokenException("The token provided is expired, malformed, revoked, or invalid for other reasons."));
                    }
                    return chain.filter(exchange);
                });
    }
}

ExceptionHandlerAdvice.java
@RestControllerAdvice
@AllArgsConstructor
//@Priority(0)
@Order(-2)
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvice implements ErrorWebExceptionHandler {

    private final ExceptionErrorFactory exceptionErrorFactory;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @ExceptionHandler(WebExchangeBindException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> handleValidationExceptions(final WebExchangeBindException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                this.exceptionErrorFactory.createError(ex.getClass().getName(), ex),
                ex.getStatusCode());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidBearerTokenException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> handleInvalidBearerTokenException(final InvalidBearerTokenException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                this.exceptionErrorFactory.createError(ex.getClass().getName()),
                HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED
        );
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ExpiredJwtException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> handleExpiredBearerTokenException(final ExpiredJwtException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                this.exceptionErrorFactory.createError(ex.getClass().getName()),
                HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED
        );
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(UnauthorisedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> handleUnauthorizedException(UnauthorisedException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                this.exceptionErrorFactory.createError(ex.getClass().getName(), ex),
                HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED
        );
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) {

        DataBufferFactory bufferFactory = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory();

        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        ErrorDto errorResponse = null;

        if (ex.getClass().equals(ExpiredJwtException.class)) {
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            errorResponse = this.exceptionErrorFactory.createError(ex.getClass().getName());
        } else if (ex.getClass().equals(InvalidBearerTokenException.class)) {
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            errorResponse = this.exceptionErrorFactory.createError(ex.getClass().getName());
        }

        DataBuffer dataBuffer = null;
        try {
            dataBuffer = bufferFactory.wrap(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(errorResponse));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            dataBuffer = bufferFactory.wrap("".getBytes());
        }

        return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Flux.just(dataBuffer));
// Also tried this
// return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.just(dataBuffer));

    }
}

I tried implement CORS filter like that with no luck. The only difference with this implementation is that i could see the preflight request (OPTIONS) on browser.
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfiguration() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://client.example.com");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("Content-Type");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("authorization");

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {
        return new CorsWebFilter(corsConfiguration());
    }


it is very clear that you have learnt spring security from looking at blogposts, and youtube videos and not used the documentation at all. I would recommend that you remove your entire home made jwtfilter, as home made security is dangerous and not recommended. And instead implement one of the already pre implemented security features that comes with spring security than building your own. And then read the CORS chapter in the spring security docs on how to implement CORS correctly. I dont really see the point of having a security framework and then try to rebuild things that already exists

Hello @Toerktumlare and thank you for the answer. On the jwtfilter you are correct and will do. On the CORS implementation though both approaches are inside the Spring Securrity documendation about WebFlux. Take for example the approach i say i tryed but did not work for me CORS WebFilter

but you dont have any functional endpoints

if you mean about this http://client.example.com.... i change it my self. for the post. This is actually an on development service that is not get live so i can't write the actual urls at the moment.

I think i found the solution. @Toerktumlare thanks for pointing to the right direction. As Toerktumlare pointed out my filters, CorsFilter and JwtAuthFilter are bypassing the default functionality of Spring Security. Although the CorsFilter is described in the documendation the best practice always by the documendation is the CorsConfigurationSource and CorsWebFilter beans.
This is the final configuration that worked for me. Again feel free to point out any bad practices.
SecurityConfiguration.java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ResourceServiceSecurityProperties.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            "/users/login"
    };

    private final ResourceServiceSecurityProperties resourceServiceSecurityProperties;

    private final CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        http
                // Disabled basic authentication
                .httpBasic(ServerHttpSecurity.HttpBasicSpec::disable)

                // Disabled CSRF
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)

                // Rest services don't have a login form
                .formLogin(ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec::disable)

                .logout(ServerHttpSecurity.LogoutSpec::disable)

                .authorizeExchange(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, AUTH_WHITELIST)
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyExchange()
                        .authenticated()
                )

                // Do not allow sessions
                .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())

                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServerCustomizer -> oauth2ResourceServerCustomizer
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()).authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveJwtDecoder reactiveJwtDecoder() {
        return ReactiveJwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(resourceServiceSecurityProperties.getIssuerUri());
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfiguration() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://client.example.com");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("Content-Type");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("authorization");

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {
        return new CorsWebFilter(corsConfiguration());
    }
}

No changes to ExceptionHandlerAdvice.java
Added CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint.java
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private final ExceptionErrorFactory exceptionErrorFactory;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> commence(ServerWebExchange exchange, AuthenticationException exception) {
        DataBufferFactory bufferFactory = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory();

        ErrorDto errorResponse = this.exceptionErrorFactory.createError(exception.getClass().getName());

        DataBuffer dataBuffer = null;
        try {
            dataBuffer = bufferFactory.wrap(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(errorResponse));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            dataBuffer = bufferFactory.wrap("Error".getBytes());
        }

        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return response.writeWith(Mono.just(dataBuffer));
    }
}

When i removed the two custom filters and added the CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint everythnig worked as expected. The CORS error was lost and the browser rendered the error body successfully.
